# JSF does not accept string parameter in my method summe of the object Satzrechner

Tags: spring, jsf

I have following JSF index.xhtml-page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputText value="Zahl1:" style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText binding="#{zahl1}" />
            <h:outputText value="Zahl2:" style="font-weight:bold" />
            <h:inputText binding="#{zahl2}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Summiere" action="#{satzRechner.summe('zahl1.value,zahl2.value')}"></h:commandButton>
            <h:outputText value="Ergebnis: #{satzRechner.summe('zahl1.value,zahl2.value')}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What I now want to is to calculate for example the String "4,8" to 12 (8+4) or "1,2" to 3 (1+2). For that i have following bean-class:

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SatzRechner {

    @Autowired //@Inject
    private Rechner taschenRechner; 
    @Autowired
    private Zahlenfabrik zahlenfabrik;

    public Integer summe(String zeichenSatz) {
        return taschenRechner.summe(zahlenfabrik.erzeugeZahlen(zeichenSatz));
    }
}
```

But this does not function:

EveryTime I get following errorCode:

> Kein übereinstimmendes navigation-case Element von View ID
>   '/index.xhtml' für die Aktion
>   `'#{satzRechner.summe('zahl1.value,zahl2.value')}'` mit dem Ergebnis '0'
>   gefunden.

Courtesy : Google Translate.

> No matching navigation-case element of View ID '/index.xhtml' for
>   action `'#{satzRechner.summe('zahl1.value, zahl2.value ')}'` with the
>   result '0' found.

What is here the problem?

Comment: the return value of an action should refer to a page, not the result of the addition of the values... You seem to miss some basics about JSF... And switching the error messages to english and searching for them on the internet helps a lot. Not a lot of developers use the JDK in German , including the germans.

Comment: Btw, your title is totally unrelated to the error. What is also wrong is that you try to have a class as a spring mananged bean AND a jsf managed bean and that is wrong. Please use a good tutorial for learning jsf

Comment: What does the message mean? You have quoted parameters in EL which are bound to `<h:inputText>` which won't be evaluated, since they are merely `String` type parameters. Moreover, you are unnecessarily using JSF annotations even though Spring is responsible for managing beans. Change the return type of `summe()` from `Integer` to `String` as you need to return an appropriate navigation case outcome from the method or use `actionListener`, if you need not perform navigation from that method (though `action` can also return `void`)